# NextJs Tailwind header styling issue

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have Nextjs project and I am using tailwind. I have an issue with styling.

expected:

- large screen (desktop or laptop) should show logo to the left and to the right contact information should show. (this is working as expected)
- smaller screen (mobile phone) should show only logo and it should be centered

issue:

- when the screen size is smaller or I adjust the browser screen to represent a smaller screen  the logo does not shift to the center of the header. Also the contact information still show

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { ShoppingBasket } from "lucide-react";

const AppHeader: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <header className="bg-[#212529] border-b border-white sm:h-[77px] lg:h-[91px]">
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4 flex justify-between items-center h-full">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <Image
            src="/path-to-your-logo.png"
            alt="Logo"
            width={190}
            height={57}
            className="sm:w-[166px] sm:h-[50px] lg:w-[190px] lg:h-[57px]"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="sm:hidden md:flex items-center space-x-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col font-medium text-white font-montserrat">
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>1503 Kelly's.</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>Clove SC 78620</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>(704) 777-7777</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>2131@gmail.com</span>
          </div>
          <div className="border-l h-[48px]"></div>
          <ShoppingBasket className="text-white h-8 w-8" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default AppHeader;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `sm:` prefix from `sm:hidden` from the `<div>` that encapsulates the right contact information so that the right contact information will have `display: none` applied until the `md:` breakpoint.

To center the logo, apply `justify-items: center` via the `justify-center` utility class, and then apply `justify-items: space-between` for screens larger than the `md` breakpoint by adding the `md:justify-between` utility class:

```js
const ShoppingBasket = () => 'ShoppingBasket';

const AppHeader = () => {
  return (
    <header className="bg-[#212529] border-b border-white sm:h-[77px] lg:h-[91px]">
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4 flex justify-center items-center h-full md:justify-between">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/190/57"
            alt="Logo"
            width={190}
            height={57}
            className="sm:w-[166px] sm:h-[50px] lg:w-[190px] lg:h-[57px]"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col font-medium text-white font-montserrat">
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>1503 Kelly's.</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>Clove SC 78620</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>(704) 777-7777</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>2131@gmail.com</span>
          </div>
          <div className="border-l h-[48px]"></div>
          <ShoppingBasket className="text-white h-8 w-8" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<AppHeader/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```